# Detect 2 duplicate values in a row from SQL db and update otherwise insert (using python)

Tags: python, mysql

I am wanting to insert into a MySQL database UNLESS two columns values are matched in which case I would like to update 2 values. Using Python.

My columns are: ID, Ticker, Subreddit, Score, Rockets and DateTime

What I am trying to do is:

INSERT a new record IF Ticker AND the DATE (only) are not existing otheriwse UPDATE Score and Rockets

What I mean by "DATE (only)" is that from the DATETIME I would only like to match the date. So if it is: 2021-02-05 09:52:54 I want to check if 2021-02-05 exists for a Ticker.

This is what a full entry looks like:

```
704   AYOLO   r/wallstreetbets    1843    0   2021-02-05 09:52:54
```

To insert into the database I currently have this:

```
def upload_to_database(ticker_collection):
  trend_data = []
  trend_data_table = "trend_data"
  trend_data_columns = "Ticker, Subreddit, Score, Rockets"
  trend_data_sql = "INSERT INTO " + trend_data_table + " (" + trend_data_columns + ") VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"

  for ticker in ticker_collection:
    ticker_subreddit = ticker_collection[ticker]['subreddit']
    ticker_score = ticker_collection[ticker]['score']
    ticker_rockets = ticker_collection[ticker]['rockets']
    
    ticker_data = (ticker, ticker_subreddit, ticker_score, ticker_rockets)

    trend_data.append(ticker_data)
  
  the_db_cursor.executemany(trend_data_sql, trend_data)
  the_database.commit()

  return the_db_cursor.rowcount, "was inserted."
```

I have read a lot about `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VALUES` but I am not sure how to incoporate this to check two columns and also how to extract and match only the date and then match it to the current date of my machine.

Comment: Are those two columns the primary key?

Comment: Not at the moment, but I could make them, do they both have to be a primary key?

Comment: Well, I suppose not.. They could also be a unique key..

Comment: I have set them to unique, how does this correlate with my code needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL can apparently create functional indexes so you might be able to get it to work without a generated column.. I didn't succeed with it on a fiddle site, but I did succeed using an indexed generated column

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blah (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  tick varchar(10),
  score varchar(10),
  dt datetime,
  d datetime generated always as (date(dt)),
  unique key x(tick, d)
);
                                  
insert into blah (score, tick, dt) values('a', 'a','2020-01-01 12:34');
                                     
insert into blah (score, tick, dt) values('new', 'a','2020-01-01 12:35')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score=VALUES(score);
```

If you comment the last line out you'll see an error about duplicate values in the key..

With the last line in instead of inserting a new record the existing row will have its score column updated to "new"

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/931XpBo8PFqMzL25uoy5zy/0

Answer (score 0):

You must set your "ticker" and "date" columns as either your primary key or a unique index. If you do that then you may set your SQL query as :

```
INSERT INTO your tablename (column_list)
VALUES (value_list)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
updatecolumn_1 = value_1,
updatecolumn_1 = value_2,
........................,
........................,
updatecolumn_n = value_n
```

;